# make some model field conditionally visible in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two field in my django model they should be editable only if user have selected 'type' as 'Dimention' otherwise they should not be visible to user.

My model is look like this code

```
from django.db import models

class Configuration(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   user_defined_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   FieldTypes = (('aD', 'Dimension'), ('aM', 'Measure'))
   type = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=FieldTypes)
   is_key = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
   unit = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

I know it is possible by using JavaScript but, I don't want to write html or js myself,Thus Can't use JavaScript for doing this.

Comment: You don't have to write HTML. Write all your JS code in a `.js` file and supply that file to ModelAdmin using [`class Media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions).

Comment: Is there a way to do it with Django functionality only..without using js myself

Comment: you need to create separate model for it and create multi-part form (wizard view) if user selects type you need to handle what to do from view. It will be lot of hazard if you try to handle this without js

Comment: The type selection happens outside the context of Django; it happens on the browser. Therefore JS is the apt place to put this code in. It is quite easy to do as well, I would recommend you check that out.

Comment: @xyres Finally does It using JS. and then i override save method to remove extra field data but that JS file is loading in all of my admin section where edit form is not present thus giving error. can you help me with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure Django-only way to achieve this is to simply reset the fields from your `ModelForm` if type is not equal to Dimension. This will appear like magic/unintended behavior; so be careful of the implementation.

For example (assuming you are using the admin interface: the same is valid for a custom ModelForm View):

```
class ConfigurationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        #  At this point; the object already has the new values set; we will have to reset as needed
        conditional_editable_fields = ['is_key', 'unit']
        config_type = form.cleaned_data.get('type')
        if config_type != 'aD':
            for field in conditional_editable_fields:
                if field in form.changed_data:  # The value has been changed by the user
                    setattr(obj, field, form.initial.get(field))  # Set the initial value
                    self.message_user(request, "Cannot edit field: {}; value has been reset".format(field), messages.WARNING)  # Inform the user that we reset the value
        return super(ConfigurationAdmin, self).save_mode(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use similar approach for this.
I it works great
In My admin.py

```
`
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name', 'user_defined_name', 'type', 'is_active')
        }),
        ('Advanced', {
            'classes': ('toggle',),
            'fields': ('is_kpi', 'unit'),
        })
    )
    actions = [disable_multiple_column, activate_multiple_column]

    class Media:
        js = ("jquery.js", "my_code.js",)`
```

I use that JS file to show and hide .

```
    `$(document).ready(function(){
        show_hide();
        $('#id_type').change(function(){
            show_hide();
        });
        function show_hide(){
            if ($("#id_type").val() == 'aM' ){
                    $(".module")[1].style.display="block"
                }
            else{
                 $(".module")[1].style.display="none"
            }
        }
    });`
```

And in case use already entered values and then change Choice of type or from some other reason these hidden field still have data. I override the save Method of models.py

```
`
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.type != 'aM':
            self.is_kpi = False
            self.unit = None
        super(Configuration, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
`
```